# Windows 10 taskbar application thumbnail on hover disappeared

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, thumbnails

Until a few days ago, whenever I would hover over an application I had open on the taskbar, it would give me a small thumbnail of the application as it was. So if I was hovering over VLC as it was playing a file, I would see a small video running. It also gave you the ability to close the application with a small x in the corner of the thumbnail.

I know I didnt make any setting changes (unless it was an accidental hotkey press). But there was a windows update around the same time this happened.

I dont know what to call this feature, taskbar hover thumbnails(?), but I would really like to turn it back on.

Since it does matter, I am using windows 10, nor have I done anything out there when it comes to settings.

Comment: There are (I think) a couple of ways this could happen. Please review the following article thoroughly: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/tenable-or-disable-taskbar-thumbnail-preview-in-windows-10

Comment: @John I tried method 1 in the link, it had no effect. I cant do 2 because its a home version of w10. I didnt do 3 because I dislike touching the registry and have not in w10.

Comment: You can try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link. Use the option to Keep Everything to begin with:   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: This morning they are back, so maybe something did work and it just required a restart.